# script execution stopped without explanation

Tags: playwright

script execution stopped without explanation

Hello,
I have a playwright script that I generated with the following command:

```
npx playwright codegen --browser=firefox
```

Below is the script:

```
Test('test', async ({ page }) => {
 await page.goto('https://128.X.Y.Z:8080/my-app/index.html');
 await page.getByPlaceholder('Login').click();
 await page.getByPlaceholder('Login').fill('1234');
 await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').click();
 await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill('1234');
 await page.getByRole('button', { name: ' Connect' }).click();
 await page.getByLabel('Visual my profil').click();
 await page.frameLocator('#iframeid7').getByRole('tab', { name: 'Job' }).click();
 await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: ' Person' }).click();
 await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: ' doctor' }).click();
});
```

I ran a test of the script with the command :

```
npx playwright test --headed --project=firefox
```

The script executes up to line `await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: ' Person' }).click();`

and then stops, it doesn't complete the script.

I ran a test in debug mode with the command :

```
npx playwright test --headed --project=firefox --debug
```

I executed the step-by-step mode by clicking on the Step Over icon (F10) on the playwrigth inspector. But when I got to the line of code

```
await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: ' Person' }).click();
```

the icon becomes greyed out and it's impossible to go any further to finish the script.

At the end of the playwrigth inspector log tab, there's the message
waiting for `getByRole('menuitem', { name: ' Person' })`

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: "there's the message waiting for getByRole('menuitem', { name: ' Person' })" -- is this an error? Can you post the actual message? Without `https://128.X.Y.Z:8080/my-app/index.html`, the problem isn't reproducible since the code looks normal.